# How to make Jackson not fail whole deserialziation process when one of the element of array has inproper value?

Tags: java, arrays, jackson, deserialization

I have following class that is POJO of JSON document:

```
public class ApiResponse {
    private boolean success;
    private List<ApiRecord> data;
}
```

I deserialize object using ObjectMapper class in the following way:

```
var apiResponse = mapper.readValue(target, ApiResponse.class);
```

I want to make Jackson treat every ApiRecord deserialization failure as not failure of whole deserialization process but instead just get a list that contains only valid parsed objects, so the wrong elements of 'data' field are acceptable (not appearing in POJO list) and not blocking the rest ones.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What is the exact error shown?

Comment: You can configure your `ObjectMapper` with the `configure()` method, and the constants in the `SerializationFeature` and `DeserializationFeature` classes. That way you can turn certain things off or on depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing add one property to the mapper object.

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
  objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
  var apiResponse = mapper.readValue(target, ApiResponse.class);
```

Comment: This is not about unknown property. It's about property that is known, but during deserialization (by custom deserializer or default one) it find out that value of field is not proper, but instead of failing whole deserialization process, it just does not add object do the array.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to write my own deserializer which in case of failure returns `null` for array's element and tag the field that needs to use this deserializer with `@com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize(using = SomeClass.class)`.